# window top flashing/channel against flat surface

Tags: windows, flashing

I have parging above the window, nothing to tuck a channel under. What is the product to use to add flashing to the top of the window in this case?

Comment: What sort of window?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand this correctly, you need a way to connect the flashing to the parging. I would advise studying the way that chimney apron flashing is attached to chimneys. In short, (maybe call a contractor to) cut a 1/2" deep groove (aka kerf or riglet) in the parging to insert the flashing. Use [window and door flashing tape](http://www.homedepot.com/p/6-in-x-75-ft-Select-Window-and-Door-Flashing-Tape-1207782/100507542) (aka double stick) and silcone to adhere the flashing.

If you hare having trouble attaching the flashing to the window or something, then (maybe upload a picture and) describe the problem more specifically.